# SearchView in ActionBar with more fragment on android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, fragment, searchview, whatsapp

I need Add SearchBar in ActionBar handle with more Fragments like whatsApp 
when Search in Tab chats get data and when Search in Tab Status get another data
How do This?This is My Code there is 3 tabs i need every tab there is SearchView

This Activity which there is on Fragments

```
  public class ActivityForIncludeFragments extends AppCompatActivity{
@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_for_include_fragments);

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

    CategoryAdapter adapter = new CategoryAdapter(this,getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    invalidateOptionsMenu();


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuItem menuItemAddData = menu.findItem(R.id.add_data);
    MenuItem menuItemActionSearch = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

    menuItemAddData.setVisible(false);
    menuItemActionSearch.setVisible(false);

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);



}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id){
        case R.id.add_stocking_warehouse:
            Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityForIncludeFragments.this,StockingWarehouse.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.add_reportes:
            Intent intentReport = new Intent(ActivityForIncludeFragments.this,TableDaliyMovmentes.class);
            startActivity(intentReport);
            break;
            }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}
 }
```

and This Fragment there is the data

```
   public class AddPremissionFragment extends Fragment implements   
     LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<ArrayList<ItemsStore>>
     ,SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
     public AddPremissionFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
public static final String ID_PERMISSION = "id";
public static final String NAME_PERMISION = "namePErmission";
public static final String NOTES_PERMISSION = "notes";
public static final String DIALOG_PERMISSION = "dialogPermission";

FloatingActionButton fab_add_permission;
ListView mListView;
public static  AdapterAddPermission adapterAddPermission;
TaskDbHelper dbHelper;
ArrayList<ItemsStore> itemsPermissions = new ArrayList<ItemsStore>();
private ProgressBar progressBarPermission;
//Identifier for the category dataloader;
public static final int PERMISSION_LOADER = 2;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

View view;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_premission, container, false);
    TextView namePremission = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.ETTypeStore);

    dbHelper = new TaskDbHelper(getActivity());
    mListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listViewAddPermission);
    progressBarPermission =(ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.progressBarPermission);

    adapterAddPermission = new AdapterAddPermission(getContext(), itemsPermissions);
    View emptyView = view.findViewById(R.id.empty_view_permission);
    mListView.setEmptyView(emptyView);
    mListView.setAdapter(adapterAddPermission);

    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //   Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Click :"+ position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ItemsStore itemSPermision = itemsPermissions.get(position);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt(ID_PERMISSION, itemSPermision.getId());
            bundle.putString(NAME_PERMISION, itemSPermision.getNamePermission());
            bundle.putString(NOTES_PERMISSION, itemSPermision.getNotes());
            // startActivity(intent);
            //  long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(TaskContract.TaskEntry._ID));
            EditPermissionFragment f = new EditPermissionFragment();
            f.setArguments(bundle);
            f.show(getFragmentManager(),DIALOG_PERMISSION);}});
    //    namePremission.setText("Name Permission");
    fab_add_permission = (FloatingActionButton)view.findViewById(R.id.fab_add_permission);
    fab_add_permission.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            new EditPermissionFragment().show(getFragmentManager(),DIALOG_PERMISSION);



        }
    });
    return view;
}
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    //Kick off the loader
    getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(PERMISSION_LOADER, null, this);
}

@Override
public Loader<ArrayList<ItemsStore>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    return new LoaderPErmission(getContext().getApplicationContext(),itemsPermissions,dbHelper);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<ArrayList<ItemsStore>> loader, ArrayList<ItemsStore> data) {
    progressBarPermission.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    adapterAddPermission.swapData(data);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<ArrayList<ItemsStore>> loader) {
    adapterAddPermission.swapData(Collections.<ItemsStore>emptyList());

}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuItem);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    itemsPermissions = dbHelper.getAllItemsPermissionBySearch(newText);
    if (itemsPermissions !=null){
        adapterAddPermission.setFilter(itemsPermissions);
        //  getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(Daily_LOADER,null,this);

    }
    return false;
}
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check which fragment is visible using this

```
 Fragment fragment = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);

  if (fragment != null && fragment.isVisible()) {
      if (fragment instanceof ChatFragment) {
         ....      
        } 
      else { }
  }
```